# Where does this text come from ? with editable

Tags: jquery, jeditable

I use the jeditable jquery plugin. My table is like that :

[image]

I have this problem : when I click on a jeditable field, this text appears :

[image]

My js code is :

```
 $('.edit').each(function(){
     $(this).editable($('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/update_role_ajax', {

         indicator  : '<img src="'+$('#url_for_ajax').val()+'/img/waiting.gif'+'">',
         tooltip    : 'Clic pour modifier la valeur',
         style      : 'inherit',
         height     : '20px',
         onchange   : 'submit',
         cssclass   : 'input',
         id         : 'id_role',
         name       : 'new_value',
         submitdata : {  
                 'id_role'   : $(this).data('id_role'),
                 'nom_champ' : $(this).data('nom_champ'),
                 '_token'    : $('meta[name="_token"]').attr( 'content' )
                    },
         callback   : function(value, settings) {

                // 

            },
         onerror    : function(settings,original,xhr){
                alert("It wasn't possible to edit. Try again");
                console.log("XHR Status: " + xhr.status)} 
        });
    });
```

Any idea where does this text come from ?

Dominique

Comment: What does your rendered markup look like? Can you provide a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That happens because it will take as editable whatever is inside the element that has `edit` class.

Most likely you have a *span* element inside the element with the `edit` class, that's why it showing that way. The editable element shouldn't contain other elements inside, just plain text.

Try to add the `edit` class to the *span* instead and it should work.

Comment: Thanks a lot Bogdan, you re right. My edit class was on the td element. I put it on the child span element and now it works fine. Merci .